# DataLayer for TagManager is not tracked in Google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I am able to dynamically construct the datalayer for tagmanager.
But it is not tracked in Google Analytics.

From the documentation provide by google, we need not use datalayer.push[] as it is rendered before the tagmanager codes.
My code for this is:

```
<script>
dataLayer = [{
"transactionId": "4NOV2013_4830a18f-15fd-4cc5-a035-0e513d3f73bb",
"transactionAffiliation":"Registration",
"transactionTotal": 0,
"transactionProducts": [{
"sku": "Lead",
"name":"Lead",
"price": 0,
"quantity": 1
}]
    }];

</script>
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-DEMO"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-DEMO');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Comment: What track type are you using? What does your rule look like?

Comment: Rule ? Its abt tracking the transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Sridhar, it seems that you are listing all required parameters, so this should work once the e-commerce tag is setup correctly. Make sure you add a new tag for e-commerce transactions:

- Tag Type: Google/Universal Analytics
- Track Type: **Transaction**

Full [official documentation](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/3002596?hl=en) from Google Tag Manager team.

Also make sure you use correct version of GTM container snippet. I can see you have replaced one of the container IDs with **GTM-DEMO**, but the other one is still visible (html?id=**GTM-KMSLVD**).

Double check the container is working correctly, then use *Preview/Debug* feature to see if the tags fires together with [GA Debug](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en) in Chrome (see the attached picture). If there is anything wrong (like argument type), GA Debug will list all the error messages in the browser console.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You are missing several syntaxes for e-commerce to work in Universal Analytics. Have you read the documentation on https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce?

What you have now is basically only the transaction saved within GTM, so there are several ways to go about doing the actual transaction. You could set up rules within GTM to fire the transaction if it sees a specific event within the dataLayer, which looks like what you have tried? If so, then you need to create a rule to fire the transaction once it sees this data.

Or, you could just send the whole transaction within the checkout page where the dataLayer itself is placed.

For this to work, and what I am seeing is missing, is the call for the ecommerce javascript library.

```
ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');
```

Also, your not sending the transaction itself using `ga('ecommerce:send');`.

Some key components from the documentation from Google is, when using the ecommerce.js library:

> To load the ecommerce plugin, use the following command:

```
ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');
```

> This command must occur after you create your tracker object and before you use any of the ecommerce specific functionality.

```
ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
  'id': '1234',                     // Transaction ID. Required.
  'affiliation': 'Acme Clothing',   // Affiliation or store name.
  'revenue': '11.99',               // Grand Total.
  'shipping': '5',                  // Shipping.
  'tax': '1.29'                     // Tax.
});

ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
  'id': '1234',                     // Transaction ID. Required.
  'name': 'Fluffy Pink Bunnies',    // Product name. Required.
  'sku': 'DD23444',                 // SKU/code.
  'category': 'Party Toys',         // Category or variation.
  'price': '11.99',                 // Unit price.
  'quantity': '1'                   // Quantity.
});

ga('ecommerce:send');
```

**UPDATE**: After a comment from questioner, I'd like to add this to my answer. What needs to be done is to set up the transaction itself to be tracked within GTM. To do this, follow theese steps:

1. Create a new tag and name it, for example, "Track transaction".
2. Select "Universal Analytics" as tag type
3. Select "Transaction" as track type
4. Add a new rule and name it, for example, "Conversion page"
5. Enter URL contains "thank-you-page" and add another field
6. Enter event equals gtm.dom

Save and publish and see if this solves your issue.

Comment: We have the rule setup that we can confirm in the google analytics GA debugger chrome extension. And the above codes looks like for regular universal analytics ecommerce transactions.
We are following this documentations https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/3002596?hl=en
pls help us to move further.

Comment: I see. Have you set up the tag to fire to track the transaction as well after the event gtm.dom is fired?

Comment: We are not using the gtm push we are directly passing the variable. I think we are missing at some formatting level. not sure what is the problem still trying to figure it out.

Comment: Please see my addendum if that might solve your issue.

Comment: Could it be that the transaction dataLayer variables that are optional e.g. transactionTax must still be included in the dataLayer, but just with empty values?

Comment: Oh, yes, that should be added too if I am not mistaken. Since the items are matched by positions (atleast they were for Classic Analytics), I believe you need to have those as well although empty.